# Two rotations at the same time, on the same axis

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, euler-angles

I need help regarding two rotations at the same time, on the same axis. One vector is approaching 90 degrees. When I press up, it should smoothly approach the angle 45 degrees above it, such that HOLDING up will still be going down. Here is a rough sketch of what I mean: [(black = vector without up, red = vector approaching 45 above black)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHXsN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the official documentation on

- `Quaternion.Lerp` [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Lerp.html)
- `Quaternion.Slerp` [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Slerp.html)

Choose whichever suits your needs.